# Move sprite to top of all elements - Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, z-order

I know how to position a CCSprite in relation to all children nodes based on

```
sprite.zOrder = 5;
```

However, I have a CCNode that is added to the CCScene and I need a child of that CCNode to be positioned above all the elements in the CCScene. Is this possible?

Comment: add the CCNode to the scene first. All its children will be 'above' anything you add after, even with the same zOrder.

Comment: Its not that simple unfortunately. The node is technically a background with elements that changes. So I'm guessing there isn't a easy way. I can find a workaround but was hoping something would be available

Comment: not possible, though in my experience you don't need a "hard" way either, just think about what the hierarchy does and whether you can't just easily program that in. Typical case being a node that should follow its parent around, but must be z ordered differently. So you don't make it a child, and the former parent simply applies its position to the former child node by sending it an objc message like adjustYourPositionToMine: ... do that after the former parent node has updated its position (update: should suffice) and you are done.

Comment: also, don't go into vertexZ, really not worth the trouble unless you need fine control over every node's draw order such as in an isometric game

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps go for manually setting the `vertexZ` property. Its hidden so you will have to `#import CCNode_Private.h`. This will break the parent children ordering the zOrder enforces but perhaps that is what you want.
You will also need to enable depth buffer `CCSetupDepthFormat: @(GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES)`